# Pure CSS DropDown Menu Dilemma (Help!)

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a Pure CSS Dropdown menu in my **banner div**:

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
        <h1><a href="http://widerdesign.co.nr/">wider design</a></h1>
        <ul id="lang">
            <li><a href="index.php">English</a></li>
            <li class="drop"><a href="es/index.php">Español</a></li>
            <li class="drop"><a href="tw/index.php">中文(繁體)</a></li>
            <li class="drop"><a href="cn/index.php">中文(简体)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 /* banner */
    #banner {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 0 0 15px 0;
        margin: 30px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 960px;
    }
    #lang {
        padding: 9px 0 0 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #lang li.drop {
        display: none;
        margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
    #lang:hover li.drop {
        display: block;
    }
```

When I hover `#lang ul`, `li.drop` are displayed as block (previously hidden). But here I have the following problems:

1. `#lang` floats to the left side (since it as absolute position I can't float it right).
2. If I position it to the right side (`right: 0;`) it sticks to the browser's window, and it doesn't move along the `margin: 0 auto;`.
3. If I use position: relative in `#banner`, and do the option 2, it works but since `#banner` has `overflow:hidden`, `li.drop` are not completely displayed.
4. I tried z-index but I'm not sure how it can works in this situation (I assigned `z-index: 100`; to `li.drop` didn't work).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pure CSS drop downs have always seemed like a fun thing to try, but ultimately useless in a real project.  Any browser that could support enough CSS to to pure CSS dropdowns could be running JavaScript, and do the same thing in much less code, and would be much easier to debug.  It's easy to make Javascript dropdowns that work all the way back to IE5.  I don't imagine the same is as easy in pure CSS

Comment: I don't understand the problem: your menu works fine.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: be sure to check out this [code review proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). I think you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

try having your sub-nav as another ul inside the li

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a title="" href="#><span>option one</span></a></li>
  <li class="sub"><a title="" href="#"><span>option two</span></a>
    <ul class="sub_nav">
      <li><a title="" href="#"><span>sub one</span></a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="#"><span>sub two</span></a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="#"><span>sub three</span></a></li>
      <li class="last_sub><a title="" href="#"><span>sub four</span></a></li>
    </ul>                
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS

```
#nav li {display: block; float: left; position: relative;}
#nav li a span {padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; border-right: 1px solid #373737; color: #dddddd; font-size: 13px; background: #2a2a2a; float: left; display: block;}
#nav li a:hover span, #nav li .active span {color: #373737; background: #bcd22c;}

#nav .sub_nav {display: none; float: left;}
#nav .sub:hover .sub_nav {display: block; margin: 38px 0 0 0; border: none; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; z-index: 5000; width: 100px;}
#nav .sub_nav li a span {padding: 10px 10px 10px 26px; line-height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; font-size: 12px; height: 20px; width: 80px; cursor: pointer; margin: 0 !important; border-right: none !important;}
#nav .sub_nav li a span:hover {}
#nav .sub_nav .last_sub a span {border: none !important;}
#nav .sub_nav li span {width: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move #lang to the right? If so, use this css for #lang:

```
 #lang {
        padding: 9px 0 0 50px;
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Then, simply adjust "50px" to whatever you want to move the div to the left or right. Let me know if that helps or not!